# phytools add.species.to.genus could not match your species to a genus

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny

I have a species tree to which I am trying to add species, which includes a tip "Geissospermum laeve". When I run:
`with_polytomes = phytools::add.species.to.genus(tree, "Geissospermum polytome1", where='root')`, the original tree is returned with the error message: 'could not match your species to a genus  check spelling, including case'.

Reproducible example:

```r
test_tree = ape::rtree(5)
test_tree$tip.label = c("t3 sp1", "t4 sp1", "t5 sp1", "t2 sp1", "t1 sp1")
with_polytomes = phytools::add.species.to.genus(test_tree, "t1 polytome1", where='root')
```

I don't understand why this is happening, if anyone could shed some light on what's causing this error that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try,

1. setting `genus=NULL`, The logic being it doesn't know which genus to add it to. Just as a precaution setting all blank space within a taxa id in the tree to `_` ...

```
add.species.to.genus(test_tree, "t1_polytome1", genus=NULL, where=c("root"))
```

Maybe replace `root` with `random` to get it working.

2. alternative using `tree` instead

```
genus.to.species.tree(test_tree, "t1_polytome1")
```

Comment: I tried lots of different combinations of parameters but in the end the only thing that resolved the issue was using underscores instead of spaces in the tree labels i.e. `test_tree$tip.label = c("t3_sp1", "t4_sp1", "t5_sp1", "t2_sp1", "t1_sp1")`. Curiously though when the tip labels are set like this, the function works  with `species = "t1_polytome1"` and `species = "t1 polytome1"`. 

WRT (2), `phytools::genus.to.species.tree(test_tree, "t1_polytome1")` returned a tree without `t1_polytome1` added and no error given, maybe because it expects  a genus-level tree.

Comment: Thanks @A.Bollans thats good debugging. In tree files removing all blank space is standard practice, in phylip format this a bug.